# Python fbx sdk dll import fails, dependency walker isn't helping

Tags: python, dll, importerror, fbx, depends

I'm attempting to use the python version of the FBX SDK and keep running into import errors. My first attempts were running under Python 3.2.3 and importing fbx gives me the

```
>>> import fbx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found
```

I checked under dependency walker and found that it was looking for Python31.DLL and couldn't find it (along with MSVCR90.DLL, GPSVC.DLL, and IESHIMS.DLL)

My first thought was to try it under Python 3.1, because it needed Python31.DLL, so I got that and ran it and got this error when trying to import fbx:

```
>>> import fbx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Now I've gone and double checked and Dependency Walker still says I'm missing all of those DLLs and I went and looked and I have all of them in C:\Windows\system32 or C:\Windows\winsxs.

Does anyone know why Dependancy Walker would say that these DLLs can't be found? Are there any other tools for figuring out, or fixing the dll load failure I am having?

Comment: The DLLs you are looking for are probably in `C:\Windows\winsxs`

Comment: MSVCR90.DLL, GPSVC.DLL and PYTHON31.DLL are all in C:\Windows\system32 and IESHIMS.DLL is buried in winsxs. Why does Dependancy Walker say that they can't be found though? What else can I do to fix the DLL load failure?

Comment: My bad. I thought you said you couldn't find them there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem.

I did need to use Python 3.1 but I mistakenly installed the 64 bit version which caused the second error you see about not being a valid Win32 application. 
I just reinstalled Python 3.1 32-bit and it is working fine now.

Comment: Changed this from a comment to an answer for better visibility.